# classList toggle displays and immediately hides the content I want to show

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I've been having issues with addEventListener on my browser lately. At first I was receiving 304 messages and then I tried to toggle on and off a classname in one of my elements.

The task is simple- I want to show a list of menu items upon clicking on the menu-icon. Everytime I click on the menu-icon, the menu items appear and then immediately disappear. I just want the items to appear when I click on the menu-icon and remain there until I click on the menu-icon again for it to disappear. For some strange reason, I get a strange blinking effect.

```js
console.log('testing');
var button = document.getElementById('mobile-menu');
var submenu = document.getElementsByClassName('submenu')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    submenu.classList.toggle('submenu--visibility');
});
```

```css
/* Resets */
/* Typography */
/* Colors */
/* Layouts */
/* Block components */

.logo{
    width: 7rem;
}
/* Elements */
.nav__icon-unit{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
/* Modifiers */
.banner--visibility{
    display: none;
}

.follow--visibility{
    display: none;
}

.submenu--visibility{
    display: none;
}

.nav--tablet-desktop{
    display: none;
}

/* Media queries/responsive design */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .banner--visibility{
        display: block;
    }
    .nav--mobile{
        display: none;
    }
    .nav--tablet-desktop{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fall Recipes for everyone</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Fall recipes for everyone">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/tachyons/tachyons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- main container -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="banner mw7 center banner--visibility">
            <a href="" class="banner__img-container">
                <img src="assets/images/ad.png" alt="" class="banner__img">
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- follow us -->
        <div class="follow flex items-center justify-between follow--visibility">
            <div class="follow__content-container flex">
                <div class="follow__text-container">
                    <span class="follow__text">Follow us on:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="follow__icons flex">
                    <div class="follow__icon">
                        <a href="#" class="follow__social">
                            <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="follow__icon">
                        <a href="#" class="follow__social">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="follow__icon">
                        <a href="#" class="follow__social">
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="follow__icon">
                        <a href="#" class="follow__social">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- include cta -->
            <div class="follow__cta-container">
                <a href="#" class="follow__cta">Get the Fallrecipes magazine</a>
            </div>
            <!-- end cta -->
        </div>
        <!-- end follow -->
        <div class="navigation">
            <!-- include mobile nav -->
            <div class="nav flex justify-between items-center pa2 nav--mobile">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#" class="logo__img-container">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" class="logo__img">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- include nav icons -->
                <div class="nav__icons flex items-center">
                    <div class="nav__icon-container mr2">
                        <a href="" class="nav__icon-unit">
                            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav__icon-container mh2">
                        <a href="" class="nav__icon-unit">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav__icon-container mh2">
                        <a href="" class="nav__icon-unit">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nav__icon-container ml2" id="mobile-menu">
                        <a href="" class="nav__icon-unit">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end nav icons -->
            </div>
            <!-- end mobile nav -->
            <!-- include tablet/desktop nav -->
            <!-- close tablet/desktop nav -->
            <div class="submenu submenu--visibility">
                <ul class="submenu__level-one">
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Browse fallrecipes</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="submenu__level-two">
                            <li class="submenu__item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="submenu__text">Meal type</span>
                                    <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="submenu__level-three">
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="submenu__item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="submenu__text">Meal type</span>
                                    <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="submenu__level-three">
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="submenu__item">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <span class="submenu__text">Meal type</span>
                                    <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="submenu__level-three">
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="submenu__item">
                                        <a href="#" class="submenu__sub-item">Appetizers</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn--primary">See all categories</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-book-open"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Fallrecipes Magazine</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-tv"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Winner Dinner TV</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-hard-hat"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Cooking Academy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-broadcast-tower"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Newsletters</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Ask the community</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="submenu__item">
                        <a href="" class="flex">
                            <span class="submenu__icon-container mr2">
                                <i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="submenu__text">Help</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="submenu__footer">
                    <a href="#" class="submenu__bottom-text">Jobs</a>
                    <a href="#" class="submenu__bottom-text">Newsroom</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end main container -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've loaded fontawesome and tachyons into the project. Here's my github repo if that's easier to look and dissect from there:
https://github.com/jginbound/Fallrecipes

Hope to know what's causing this- thank you!

Comment: Most likely, the menu has a hyperlink that's causing navigation. Remove it so that you only get the CSS effect and no navigation.

Comment: wow that was the issue! but curious as to why that caused the problem in the first place- and what if this were a real site with actual hyperlinks? would it be possible to create a menu with actual links and still get that toggle effect? anyway, thank you!